rabbitmq integration with datadog
I want to integrate rabbitmq in datadog to monitor the queues, events, failues.
So far I have installed the Datadog agent, created an account in datadog. I have intstalled the Rabbitmq integration in Datadog. My rabbitmq localhost is up and running. I am unable to understand what should I edit in conf.d/datadog.yaml file to capture the metrics in datadog? Can anyone guide me henceforth ?

Is this relevant? Specifically, you asked "what should I edit in conf.d/datadog.yaml file...?" - and they say "Collecting logs is disabled by default in the Datadog Agent, enable it in your datadog.yaml file: logs_enabled: true". There may be various other steps you need... This may not be the only thing.
